# Sync'ing ACL permissions in a NodeJS application using MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, security, acl, database

Currently using the Node ACL module from:

https://github.com/OptimalBits/node_acl

This is working a treat but now the requirement is have to reflect any changes to our security config in our ACL layer.

What Im looking for is a clean way to iterate over the roles defined in our security config, decide whether the permissions/resources have changed and if they have update or remove them.

Here is a sample security config file, take the scenario where 'put' is removed from the resource /projectId.

```
"roles":{
   "itemRole":[
      {
         "roles":"owner-projectId",
         "allows":[
            {
               "resources":"/projectId",
               "permissions": ["put", "post", "patch","get","delete"]
            },
           {
               "resources":"/projectId/settings",
               "permissions": ["put"]
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "roles":"collaborator-projectId",
         "allows":[
            {
               "resources":"/itemId",
               "permissions":["put","post", "patch","get"]
            },
            {
               "resources":"/api/resource/itemId",
               "permissions":["put", "post", "patch","get"]
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "roles":"spectator-newId",
         "allows":[  ]
      },
      {
         "roles":"admin-newId",
         "allows":[
            {
               "resources":"/api/resource/itemId/update",
               "permissions":[ "put"]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

The following query will allow me iterate over the different roles and return all the allows for that resources, these allow_* should match what is currently in the security.config:

```
db.getCollection('authACLresources').find(  { _bucketname: {"$regex":"allows_*"}, key: { '$in': [ 'spectator-2bc240c6ffa988260b501922' ] }})
```

I can then look at the different permissions and compare - just wondering if there is a better way to do this? I know the node ACL module has a method called whatResources but doesn't give you the permissions just the resources.